# vb.net and css: For loop to create 2 controls and place side by side 'n' times each time on a new line

Tags: css, vb.net

I'm trying to create a list in my NavMenuLeft control which has two controls per line, a label and an adjacent imagebutton (a typical delete cross)

I've played around with various CSS settings and it's defeating me right now.  The below is the closest I can get to what I want so far - but it displays the first label, then on a new line it displays the 2nd label with the 1st image and so on until the final line is just the final image.

Here's the vb I'm using, which is working as expected so far (it's not finished, so I know for example all of the imagebuttons are going to perform the same action)

```
For n = 0 To ClickedTextArray.Length - 1

        Dim SelectedMedia As New Label
        SelectedMedia.Text = ClickedTextArray(n)
        SelectedMedia.ID = ClickedTextArray(n)
        SelectedMedia.CssClass = "leftsidebaritem SelectedMedia"
        NavMenuLeft.Controls.Add(SelectedMedia)

        Dim Delete As New ImageButton
        Delete.ImageUrl = "\Images\DeleteRed.png"
        Delete.ID = "DeleteImage_" & ClickedNameArray(n)
        Delete.CssClass = "DeleteImage"
        Delete.PostBackUrl = "\Main.aspx"
        NavMenuLeft.Controls.Add(Delete)

    Next
```

The referenced CSS classes:

```
.DeleteImage
{
height:9px;
float:right;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.leftsidebaritem
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px 5px;
}

.SelectedMedia 
{
background-color: #5AABF2;
text-align: left;
font-family: verdana,arial,serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
}
```

Can anyone help me out here? I'm not expecting someone to give me the answer, I want to understand the behavior I'm seeing and learn how to correct it.

I've pasted in what I think are the most pertinent pieces of code, but if more is needed then just let me know.

Thanks,

Chowie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a fiddle (or similar) I can only guess.

Looking at your code I would say you need to add your `DeleteButton` in **before** the label. When a float is used (left or right) the floated element needs to appear *before* the other elements it is being floated around. Essentially the CSS is floating your cross to the right of the *next* element, thus appearing on the next line.

So swap the two code blocks on the server so it goes Button > Label and report back.